# Proper Timing in Priority Scheduler

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

I want to write a scheduler (in Java, which is not important for my question). Each task can have a priority value (float from 0.1 to 1.0). The higher that priority value, the more processing time a task should receive. The scheduler is called in a loop which runs forever, each iteration has a maximum processing time (e.g. 10 ms).

In a book I found this scheduling algorithm (in pseudo code):

```
update(timeToRun):
    # totalPrio has been set to the sum of all task priorities
    lastTime = time()
    for each task in tasks:
        currentTime = time()
        timeToRun -= currentTime - lastTime
        availableTime = timeToRun * task.prio / totalPrio
        task.process(availableTime)
        lastTime = currentTime
```

So let's say I have two tasks, each with a priority of 0.5, so `totalPrio` is set to 1.0 and both tasks should receive equal processing time. The `update()` function is called with a value `timeToRun` of 10.

If the first task really does stop after exactly 5 ms, then the second task should receive 5 ms `availableTime` as well. However, with the algorithm above that doesn't work: `timeToRun` would be 5 in the second iteration, so `availableTime` would be set to 2.5 in the second iteration (which is obvisouly wrong).

Also, the scheduler should recognize if a task takes longer or shorter than the maximum time it received. For example, if the first task has received a maximum time of 5 ms, but it only took 2 ms, then the remaining tasks would receive more time.

How would I implement this?

Comment: I dont understand what is your question, first you say your language is java which is not important, and in the end you  want to know how to implement? java is important or not?

Comment: @AliAmiri: I have described the issue with the code above. I am asking how to solve these issues. But nevermind, I found a solution already. Will post it as answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. For the records: The code snippet above works, but only if you update the `totalPriority` value in each iteration of the `for` loop. In fact you need to subtract the priority of the task from `totalPriority` after the call to `task.process(availableTime)`. That way the `availableTime` is always calculated correctly in each loop iteration.